# How to manage multiple states with session on a website?

Tags: security, session, authentication, token, session-state

Any help is really appreciated for the following scenario:

How Amazon.com is managing different level of authentication, once at when you visit the site and second when you go to "Your Account"-> "Login & Security" as a security feature?

User logs in (i.e. authenticates) to a website and there is no activity for 7 days. The user revisits the website then user is asked to authenticate again. This can be implemented using cookies but due to security issue, it was implemented using the session token from the server side. After 7 days, when the expired token is provided by the browser, user is challenged to re-authenticate again.

Now, the new requirement is that if the user logs in and visits "Your Account" page then,

1. if the user still on "Your Account" page and there is no activity for 10 minutes, then user should be challenged to re-authenticate again.

OR.

2. if the user comes out of the "Your Account" page and revisits the "Your Account" page after 10 minutes, then user should be challenged to re-authenticate again.

So with the token, I can manage only one time period of inactivity, how can I handle multiple states, i.e. state (7 days) and partial state (10 minutes).

What is the industry practice to handle this scenario? Don't want to use cookies as security issue. And as an SSO provider is being used for authentication, use of database will be the last option.

-- David.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How you could handle this is going to boil down to the implementation details of your current expiring session token logic.

A common way to do it is to store your session tokens in a database or in-memory cache. If that's the case, you could simply add a new column that indicates when the user opened the accounts page.

As an example, your new column could be called `accountSettingsStartTime`. Normally it would have no value, but when the user navigates to the accounts page, it would be populated with the current time. When the user navigates away from the accounts page, you could clear it out. Then, when you check a security token, you just need to check your standard 7 day expiry as well as checking the `accountSettingsStartTime` column and ensuring it's within the last 10 minutes.

Alternatively, you could give the user a whole new session token with an expiry of 10 minutes when they navigate to account settings, and enforce the usage of *that* token for operations that involve account settings. You could then check that token when account settings are changed and ask the user to re-authenticate if it has expired (and invalidate their standard 7 day token). Of course, this would require more effort on the client side.

As they say, there's more than one way to skin a cat :)